# Stripe-API: Is Idempotent Requests supported for PaymentIntent?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to migrate my code to PaymentIntent and I used [Idempotent Requests](https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests) in `charge::create`, does it still work for PaymentIntent?

Comment: Yes, but you will use the Idempotent Key on paymentIntent creation as PaymentIntent is creating charges in the background without the need of creating charge explicitly. 
And paymentIntent could only create one successful charge thus itself ensure there will be no double charge issue.